# Why does MySQL server not respect bind_address?

Tags: networking, mysql

**Background**

I'm setting up a MySQL server. Its configuration file (my.cnf) does not have the `bind_address` option. As I understand from [its documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bind_address), its value defaults to `*`, which *should* make the server listen on all IPv4 or IPv6 addresses.

**Problem**

When I start the MySQL server, I expect it to listen to IPv4. Instead, it listens only to IPv6 as I've checked below.

```shell
$ netstat -nlt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN
# -- snip --
```

Why is this happening? And how can I let the MySQL server listen to IPv4 address?

**What I have checked so far:**

- I made sure that there are no other configuration file that unintentionally overrides the `bind_address`. When I query `SELECT @@bind_address`, it correctly shows `*` as intended.
- I confirm that IPv4 networking is configured on my system. Running `ip addr show` shows that `eth0` is assigned an IPv4 address. In fact, I don't think my system is configured for IPv6, as I don't see any `inet` with IPv6.
- When I explicitly set `bind_address=0.0.0.0` in my.cnf and then restart the server, the server still listens to IPv6 address, showing the same `netstat` output above.
- There are no other MySQL server instances running on my system.

**Environment**

- MySQL server: v8.0.36
- OS: CentOS 7

Comment: Have you tried connecting to IPv4 address?

Comment: @AlexD When I run `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1`, I'm able connect. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @AlexD On the other hand, when I try to connect to the MySQL server from another machine as `sql-user` and setting the `-h` option equal to the hostname of the MySQL server, I'm unable to connect. The network properly configured, and the MySQL user account, credentials and grants for `sql-user` are also properly configured.

Comment: Connect to the IPv4 address (not 127.0.0.1) from the server itself.

Comment: @AlexD When I `ping <self ipv4>`, it shows 100% transmitted. Is that how I should check? Sorry, I'm new to network-related stuff.

Comment: You are debugging a MySQL connection. Connect with `mysql`.

Comment: @AlexD Oh, I see what you mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote from the documentation you linked:

> If the address is *, the server accepts TCP/IP connections on all server host IPv4 interfaces, and, if the server host supports IPv6, on all IPv6 interfaces. Use this address to permit both IPv4 and IPv6 connections on all server interfaces. This value is the default.

By default on Linux listening on a IPv6 socket also accepts IPv4 connections, so it won't show a separate `tcp` socket in the `netstat` output but still would work with IPv4.

Comment: When I run `mysql -p -u sql-user -h <self ipv4>`, I confirm that I'm able to connect. Didn't know that's how to interpret the output of `netstat`. Thanks.